# Xcode 4.5 project not detecting iphone 4s

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5, ios5

In one of my app developed in Xcode 4.5 iphone 4s is not detecting and it is just showing as ios device.

I have added udid of the phone,created the app id of the app,configured provisioning profile and selected the udid and app id and created an active provisioning profile.

I downloaded it and it shows a valid profile in the organizer. I have configured plist file and made Build identifier as `com.companyname.appname` just similar to the app id(I excluded the id number in front of the app id). Still it is not detecting the phone.But other xcode project created in the same version detects the phone.

Could you please help me to sort this out?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your deployment target?

Comment: My Development target shows as iOS Device

Comment: I mean Project > Summary > Deployment target

Comment: the development target is 6.0

Comment: Thanks Dave It is ok right now but now got another compiler error.
 "A valid provisioning profile matching the application's Identifier 'com.cubettech.gosayit ' could not be found"

Comment: In the Project Section I could select the correct provisioning profile in the code siging section. But in the case of target I could not see the one.Instead it shows profile doesnot match the identifier.

Comment: Maybe your phone is not added to your developer profile.

Comment: @Dave : No I have added my phone and selected the phone while creating the provisioning profile.

Answer (score 1):

To identify the device, set the deployment target to your iPhone's iOS version in Project > Summary > Deployment target.